# Salesforce.com Id attribute seems to have a 15 and 18 character value, whats the difference?

Tags: soap, salesforce, apex-code

When using the SOAP API to work with salesforce.com (SFDC) it seems that the primary key in the underlying database is Id.  Well there seems to be two representations of this value as either a 15 character version or an 18 character version.

I have been using the 18 since it is clearly more specific, but what is contained in the last three digits, that they can be dropped, seemingly?

Anyone understand what this is all about?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From the [Web Services API Developer's Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/field_types.htm#i1435616):

> ID fields in the Salesforce.com user
>   interface contain 15-character,
>   base-62, case-sensitive strings. Each
>   of the 15 characters can be a numeric
>   digit (0-9), a lowercase letter (a-z),
>   or an uppercase letter (A-Z). Two
>   unique IDs may only be different by a
>   change in case.
>
> Because there are applications like
>   Access which do not recognize that
>   50130000000014c is a different ID from
>   50130000000014C, an 18-digit,
>   case-safe version of the ID is
>   returned by all API calls. The 18
>   character IDs have been formed by
>   adding a suffix to each ID in the
>   Force.com API. 18-character IDs can be
>   safely compared for uniqueness by
>   case-insensitive applications, and can
>   be used in all API calls when
>   creating, editing, or deleting data.
>
> If you need to convert the
>   18-character ID to a 15-character
>   version, truncate the last three
>   characters. Salesforce.com recommends
>   that you use the 18-character ID.

Comment: Well there you go.  Thanks!  That answers that!  And in 4 minutes too!  Double wow!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but just in case it is useful to someone...

If you want to do ad-hoc conversions of Id's, rather than programatically, then this Chrome extension makes it easy:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sf-15-to-18/cogllpmaoflgaekieefhmglbpgdgmoeg

FYI - I'm the developer. Please use the feedback form on the app if you'd like to suggest any improvements or additional functionality.

Thanks!